# Trying to show warning message in place of another when form is submited

Tags: php

I have a login form, and when I acess this login page I have a warning message saying: "Enter your acess data to start session".

And then Im validating if mail is valid or if is empty, and I want to give warning messages for this, and I want these error messages appear in place of "Enter your acess data to start session".

So I create a variable $showWarning = false, and I just show my message "Enter your acess data to start session" if this variable is false.

And the, when I want to give other warning messages I put my  variable true, $showWarning = true.

But it is not working, Im getting the two warnings at the same time.

Do you see what can be wrong?

```
$showWarning = false;
```

```
<?php
    if(!(isset($_GET['remember'])))
    {
        echo '<h1>Login:</h1>   ';
        if($showWarning ==false){
            echo '<span>Enter your acess data to start session.</span>';  
        }
        if(isset($_POST['sendForm'])){
            $f['email'] = $_POST['email'];
            $f['pass'] = $_POST['pass'];

         if(!$f['email'] || !valMail($f['email'])){
             $showWarning = true;
             echo '<span>Email is empty.</span>';
         }
         else if(strlen($f['pass']) <5 || strlen($f['pass']) > 10){
            echo '<span>Pass must have between 5 and 10 chars.</span>';
            $showWarning = true; 
         }
     }
```

Then I have my form:

```
<form name="login" action="" method="post">
      <label class="label">
          <input placeholder="Email" type="text" name="email" />
      </label>
      <label class="label">
           <input type="password" placeholder="Pass" name="pass" />
           <input type="submit" value="Login" name="sendForm" />
           <a href="index.php?remember=true">Forgot pass</a>
      </label>        
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `$showWarning` before it is defined. Also, you don't have any logic to check to see if a warning is displayed before attempting to show another.

Based on what I see in your code, that check isn't even necessary. Just check if the form is submitted. If so, show any errors that may arise during validation. If not, show your "Enter your access data to start session" message.

```
    if(isset($_POST['sendForm'])){
        $f['email'] = $_POST['email'];
        $f['pass'] = $_POST['pass'];

         if(!$f['email'] || !valMail($f['email'])){
             echo '<span>Email is empty.</span>';
         }
         else if(strlen($f['pass']) <5 || strlen($f['pass']) > 10){
            echo '<span>Pass must have between 5 and 10 chars.</span>';
         }
    }
    else {
        echo '<span>Enter your access data to start session.</span>';  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still new to php, and with such an easy solution and I was here complicated! Thank you John Conde!